# Problems running Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I've just installed Jupyter Notebook so I can follow the Udemy Python Bootcamp course.

I already had a fully working install of Python 3.71 and Pycharm and then installed Jupyter Notebook with:

```
pip install jupyter
```

This was successful other than messages about the some files not being in the PATH environment variable.  I manually added the folder to PATH.

I have run Jupyter Notebook at the command prompt with:

```
jupyter notebook
```

So far so good - Jupyter Notebook home screen appears in my browser with all the expected folders, Documents, Desktop etc listed.

However if I try and left click on one to see its contents then it pauses for a few seconds and just displays the following (not very descriptive) error:

> Server error: error

The error as a screen shot:

[image]

I'm absolutely stuck and can't progress my course without Jupyter Notebook.

I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit
Firefox (Quantum 64.0)
Bitdefender Internet Security 2018

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
pip install --upgrade jupyterhub
```

I solved the problem using this command.